# Focus on an EditText within a row from a ListView without user input

Tags: android, listview, focus

so i'm adding a row to ListView. This row contains an EditText, Spinner and a Button.
I can select the last added row and it's corresponding EditText.
Now I want to focus this object and edit it.
I've already tried with an InputManager, a handler, invalidating the whole view.
But it never focuses on the object.
However when I add a OnFocusChangeListener() to the EditText, requestFocus() triggers the event.
Just the UI is not being updated. Same goes for changing the text. While debugging the value of the EditText are changed, but the UI doesn't get updated.

Comment: Just a reminder - it is bad practice to have focusables in listview

Comment: Ok but I need to dynamically add items, seemed like the obvious solution. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Didn't try by myself, but can you try this way please.

```
    View childView = (View) listView.getChildAt(INTEGEER_POSITION);
    EditText editTextTFocus = (EditText) childView.findViewById(R.id.etxId);
    editTextTFocus.requestFocus();
```

Idea is that, to get specific vieew from listview with specific position.
And then access that particular view and giving it focus.

Comment: Thanks for the answer fixed it by adding it in the adapter when certain requirements are met.

Comment: Yes, which seems weird to me, essentially it should be the same object. But yeah it works now.